# Trying to use RegEx (in JS) to get all values delimited by a special character, between two terminators

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to use regex to find multiple instances of a custom formatted string (For the sake of this post, lets call them **macros**) out of a larger string. The macro is basically a string that starts with `{` and ends with `}`, then has *lower case alphabetical characters*, *numerical values*, *hyphens*, and (maybe) *periods*, all delimited by a colon (`:`)

**The first segment of the macro** *(and sometimes the only part)* can be either a *numerical value*, or *lower case alpha characters*, between 1 and 5 characters in length. **Examples**:

1. `{foo}`
2. `{barbaz}`
3. `{1}`
4. `{1234}`

But then, just to make it more complicated, these *macros* may have  **"modifiers"**, which are all separated by colons. These modifiers can be:

- Alpha characters *one or two characters long* (EG: *a*, *ab*)
- Numerical values  (EG: *12*, *1*, *1123123*)
- Numerical values with a hyphen somewhere in the middle of the numerical values, or before it  (EG: *1-2*, *-12*)

#### Example Macros

Heres a short list of possible macros that will/can be used, and the Regex array result I'm looking for

1. *Macro:* `{foo}` *Regex Match:* `["foo"]`
2. *Macro:* `{foo:ab:cd:e:f:g}` *Regex Match:* `["foo","ab","cd","e", "f","g"]`
3. *Macro:* `{bar:1-3}` *Regex Match:* `["bar","1-3"]`
4. *Macro:* `{baz:r:uc}` *Regex Match:* `["baz","r","uc"]`
5. *Macro:* `{quux:1:2:uc}` *Regex Match:* `["quux","1","2","uc"]`

#### Example Paragraph

I need need this query to be able to find multiple macros in a larger paragraph, for example:

```
My name is {namel:uf}, {namef:uf}, I go to {highschool:uw}. My computer username is {namef:1:l}{namel:l}
Test string: {foo}
Test string: ucfirst: {foo:uf}
Test string reversed/uppercase: {foo:u:r}
First 3 chars of test string: {foo:3}
Last 2 chars of test string: {foo:-2}
```

And I'm looking for a regex pattern that would return:

```js
[
    ['namel','uf'],
    ['namef','uf'],
    ['highschool','uw'],
    ['namef','l',0],
    ['namel','l'],
    ['foo'],
    ['foo','uf'],
    ['foo','u','r'],
    ['foo',3],
    ['foo','-2']
]
```

#### Progress Thus Far

I've been working on this for a bit, and I'm pretty sure im somewhat close.... The pattern I have right now is:

```js
/\{(([a-z]{1,10}|\d+)+)(\:([a-z]{1,2}|\-?\d+|\d+\-\d+)*)*\}/gm
```

Then heres the **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qR9rN7/1)** instance.

As you can see, it matches the macros just fine, but I'm running into two problems:

#### Problems

1. It will match the `:` character that separates the modifiers
2. It doesn't seem to match *all* of the modifiers. Take a look at **#2** in the Regex101 test strings, which is `{foo:ab:cd:e:f:g}`. I would expect the result to be: `["foo","ab","cd","e","f","g"]`, but instead, it matches `["foo","foo",":g","g"]`.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

-J

### Update

I think I fixed problem *#1* listed above, where it was returning some of the `:` delimiters. All I did was add a `?:` to the group that started the pattern by looking for the colon, making it a  *non-capturing* group. (Also made another change with now the numerical values are processed, but thats not relevant)

**Heres the new pattern**

```js
/\{(([a-z]{1,10}|\d+)+)(?:\:([a-z]{1,2}|\d*\-?\d+)*)*\}/gm
```

Heres the updated [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qR9rN7/3) example. You can still see that **problem #2** persists, meaning it doesn't match EVERY macro modifier, it looks like it just matches the first and the last..

Thanks!

Comment: _"And I'm looking for a regex pattern that would return:"_  How would `['namef','l',0],
    ['namel','l']` be matched from given string?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry about that. Just updated it. Added this to the example paragraph: `My computer username is {namef:1:l}{namel:l}`, which *should* result in the `['namef','l',0], ['namel','l']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\{\w+\}|\{\w+:(\w+|\d+)\}|\{\w+:(\w+|\d+):(\w+|\d+)\}/g`, `.map()`, `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\{|\}/g`, `.split()` with `RegExp` `/:/`

```js
var str = `My name is {namel:uf}, {namef:uf}, I go to {highschool:uw}. My computer username is {namef:1:l}{namel:l}
Test string: {foo}
Test string: ucfirst: {foo:uf}
Test string reversed/uppercase: {foo:u:r}
First 3 chars of test string: {foo:3}
Last 2 chars of test string: {foo:-2}`;

var res = str.match(/\{\w+\}|\{\w+:(\w+|\d+)\}|\{\w+:(\w+|\d+):(\w+|\d+)\}/g);

res = res.map(s => s.replace(/\{|\}/g, "").split(/:/));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yeah, already doing that actually, i just figured there would be a pure regex solution

Comment: @Justin What do you mean by "pure regex"? Requirement is to return an `Array` containing matches from a `String`, yes?